# How to check the SQL Data base running status using Batch script

Tags: batch-file

I am checking the table count every time using this command, but i want to check automatically using batch script

```
sqlcmd -S database\SQLEXPRESS -E -i "C:\script\script_SQL\SQL_report.sql"
```

every 5 mins my table is adding 1000 rows, so i want to check whether the table is added 1000 rows or not

i have already a script to check the last modified time of the file, but i want to check the table has been updated with 1000 row or not, so that i can enable the backup SQL if the table is not updated or not

```
    @echo off
    setlocal
    set File=C:\script\logs.txt
    set Interval=400
    for %%a in ("%File%") do set FileName=%%~nxa
    set OldFileTime=X
    :Loop
    for %%a in ("%File%") do set NewFileTime=%%~ta
    echo [%Date%][%Time%] '%FileName%' last modified: %NewFileTime% 
   ping.exe -n %Interval% localhost >NUL
    if not "%OldFileTime%"=="%NewFileTime%" (
        set OldFileTime=%NewFileTime%
        goto :Loop
    )
    echo [%Date%][%Time%] '%FileName%' has not been modified for %Interval% seconds!>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways to wait 5 minutes. Here is one.

```
waitfor /t 300 seconds 2>nul
```

Comment: What about `timeout /T 300`?

Comment: yes this above code is working good and it helped me lot thank you ..!